# What is the difference between `minikube cache list` and `minikube image list`

Tags: minikube

These two commands appear to list the images which are available in minikube. Obviously one refers to images that are 'in cache' and the other does not however it is not clear where the images being listed by `minikube image list` reside if not in the cache, or how images could be in the list returned by `minikube image list` but *not* be returned by `minikube cache list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences between them are that `image list` shows all images in cluster and `cache list` shows images which you added manually. You can read more about [Offline usage](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/offline/) and about [Pushing images](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/)

> `minikube start`  caches all required Kubernetes images by default. This default may be changed by setting  `--cache-images=false`. These images are not displayed by the  `minikube cache`  command.

To add Docker image to Minikube you can use:

```
minikube image load <name-of-docker-image>
```

Here is an example:

```
user@minikube:~/myproject$ minikube cache list
user@minikube:~/myproject$ minikube image load helloapp:v1
user@minikube:~/myproject$ minikube cache list
helloapp:v1
user@minikube:~/myproject$
```